# Why IntelliJ IDEA uses scala 2.10.6 for play2 configuration?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I use:

- scala version 2.11.8 everywhere in the project, this version is explicitly specified in `build.sbt`
- sbt version 0.13.13, which specified both in project/build.properties and IDE settings

IntelliJ IDEA uses the correct version of scala for tests running and project building (output is in `...target/scala-2.11...`), but not for play2 application. The latter one for some reason uses scala 2.10: `[info] Compiling 86 Scala sources to .../target/scala-2.10/classes...`.

The only idea I have is that IDEA uses the default scala of the sbtlauncher (it uses 2.10.6 when run from console), despite the explicit declaration in build file.

Comment: Can you provide an example project and logs that make this issue reproducible? Ideally open an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL